# Choosing a contour for residue integral

Tags: integration, contour-integration, residue-calculus

How can I evaluate
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(bx)}{x^2+1}dx \quad(b>0)$$
using residue calculus? I tried computing the residue of  $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{z\exp(ibz)}{z^2+1}dz$ at $z=i$ and taking the imaginary part of it, but what contour should I use so that only the integral over the real axis is left?

Comment: What is $b$? If it is a positive real number then take half a circle. The complex function is $\frac{ze^{ibz}}{z^2+1}$. To bound it on the circle path you will probably need Jordan's lemma.

Comment: @Mark How can it be a semicircle if the limit is from 0 to infinity? Won't it be a quarter of a circle?

Comment: Yes, but the real function you integrate is even, so you can just find the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and then divide by $2$ to get the integral from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Why is it even if there's x in the numerator?

Comment: Did you forget the $\color{blue}{\sin}$?

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you.